# xpages: HTML table in computed field

Tags: javascript, xpages

I am sorry if the solution for this question is simple but I just don't know how to solve it.

In a blank xpage, I intend to use a computed field to display html type table.

I write some code in the computed field:

```
var otable = "<table>"; //open table tag
var ctable = "</table>"; // close table tag
var otr = "<tr>"; //open tr tag
var ctr = "</tr>";// close tr tag
var otd = "<td>";//open td tag
var ctd = "</td>";// close td tag
var content = new Array(@Unique((@DbLookup(@DbName(),"viewname","keyword",4))); //use dblookup to retrieve value from a view 
var displaytemp = "";
var displayfinal = "";

for (var i = 0; i < content.length;i++)
{
    displaytemp = content[i];
}

displayfinal = otable + otr + otd + displaytemp + ctd + ctr + ctable;
```

I set the computed field content type to HTML and run it, the result is e.g.

```
value1,value2,value3
```

When I change the content type to text and run it, the result is e.g.

```
<table><tr><td>value1</td></tr></table>,<table><tr><td>value2</td></tr></table>,<table><tr><td>value3</td></tr></table>
```

I didn't put the "otable" and "ctable" in the loop, I don't understand why it appears depends on the content.length.

I tried this code but the result is the same.

```
displayfinal = "<table><tr><td>" + displaytemp + "</td></tr></table>"
```

Grateful if someone let me know the mistake. Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend the repeatControls approach, but I've had numerous examples where `escape="false"` does work, so something specific might be different in your markup.

Answer (score 2):

Create the table using a repeat control on the XPage itself, not inside a field on the XPage. The datasource of the repeat can be computed using your formula, too.

Comment: Check out this XSnippet from Tony McGuckin for creating a table layout in repeat controls https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=repeat-with-header-and-footer-facets